# Does conservation of energy across "worlds" explain probabilistic filtering of photons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, visible-light, quantum-interpretations

We can set up a light filter and a light source such that angling the filter may block out some/all of the light. For example, with a certain filter angle we might see that $30\%$ of the original light passes through the filter, with the filter blocking the remaining $70\%$.

But if we send a single photon out from that same light source, with the filter angled the same way, instead of absorbing a percentage of the photon (which is impossible), the photons passes through probabilistically: $30\%$ of the time, it passes through, and $70\%$ of the time it does not.

(This is described in [this 3Blue1Brown video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MzRCDLre1b4&list=PLAXduLXaVM5yOkCQRmMB4r7g5NFM3rJrJ&index=3&t=0s) and [this minutephysics video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zcqZHYo7ONs))

This probablistic filtering seems to violate conservation of energy. If the photon passes completely through the filter, then we seem to have gained energy from nothing. If the photon fails to pass through the filter, then energy has disappeared.

One explanation for this my professor posed used the many worlds interpretation. An approximate, math-less summary is: if the photon should've lost $70\%$ of it's energy, then what happens instead is that in every $7$ out of $10$ worlds, the photon did not pass through the filter. In the other $3$ worlds, it passed through just fine. Thus, conservation of energy is not violated if we expand our scope to multiple worlds.

Is this plausible? Please forgive me if this is a stupid or obvious question, I am but a student.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine you replace the probabilistic filter with a deterministic one, either opaque or transparent.  Is there a conservation of energy problem with these setups?

There doesn't seem to be.  Energy is delivered to the lamp, which produces a photon.  The energy travels with the photon to the filter.  If opaque, the filter gains the energy.  If transparent, the energy leaves the system.

If neither of these situations is problematic, I don't understand where the issue is with a combination of the two.  The probabilistic filter is just doing these two actions.

> When a photon passes through a 70/30, it either passes through or doesn't.

Agreed.

> When the photon passes through, energy is created because even though the filter absorbed some energy, the full photon still passed through.

No, zero energy is absorbed by the filter if the photon passes.  For the purposes of this experiment, we can assume the photon interaction is complete, one way or the other.  Either even can occur with some probability.  But for the absorption event, 100% of the energy is absorbed, and for the transmission event 0% of the energy is absorbed.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean by replacing the probablistic filter with a deterministic one. My understanding was that probablistic events arise not because of the filter, but because a single photon was sent through a filter. What is the difference between a probablistic and deterministic filter?

Comment: The probabilistic events are due to the interaction of the photon with the filter.  It has some probability of being absorbed by the filter and some probability of passing through.  We could create one that instead of your 70/30 chances had 100/0 chances.  That would be deterministic.  In neither case should there be a problem with conservation of energy.  Can you explain more where you think the energy is being created or being destroyed?

Comment: When a photon passes through a 70/30, it either passes through or doesn't. When the photon passes through, energy is created because even though the filter absorbed some energy, the full photon still passed through. If the photon doesn't pass through, then whatever energy wasn't absorbed by the filter is destroyed. That was my thinking but perhaps it is incorrect somewhere

Comment: Expanded a bit on the interaction in the answer.

Comment: @JamesRonald The filter cannot absorb some of the photons energy. It either absorbs all of it or none of it. If a photon passes through then the filter absorbed none of the energy. If a photon does not pass through, then the filter absorbed all of the photons energy.

Comment: @BillAlsept But I thought the alignment of the filter with the light source prevents complete absorption or complete passing through? It's not like the filter moves to be the appropriate orientation when the light passes through, right?

Comment: @JamesRonald that’s not the way it works. For instance if you have unpolarized light, 50% will go through the filter. I guarantee you that 50% of those photons were not already aligned with that polarized. And to be more specific, if you have polarized light and you run it through a polarizer set at 45°, 50% of the protons will make it through even though they’re not lined up.

Comment: @BillAlsept I see, that makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There's no contradiction with energy conservation, and that holds for any interpretation of quantum mechanics you use. In the "standard" collapse picture used in introductory textbooks, the photon either gets through or it doesn't. When it gets through, the energy goes to the detector. When it doesn't, it stays with the photon. In both cases, energy is conserved.

You could also just keep track of the full quantum state of the detector and the photon; I suppose that's what you mean by "many worlds". In this case, the initial quantum state is
$$|\text{photon present}, \text{detector hasn't clicked} \rangle.$$
Afterward, the quantum state is
$$c_1 |\text{photon present}, \text{detector hasn't clicked} \rangle + c_2 |\text{no photon}, \text{detector has clicked} \rangle$$
for suitable coefficients $c_1$ and $c_2$. Both branches of the wavefunction have the same energy, so there's again no problem.

I suspect your misconception is that "part" of the photon's energy goes to the detector, but "all" of the photon gets through. That's kind of mixed up. The detector's state has always either completely absorbed the photon, or not absorbed it at all, or a superposition of the two. There's no situation where the detector definitely ends up with the energy of half a photon.

Comment: The two terms in your superposition don't necessarily have the same expectation value for the energy.  It is only conserved across the whole state.  https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01889375

Answer (score 0):

If the system has definite energy, it is a stationary state, so the question is moot.  The more interesting case is when the system is nonstationary and we only have an expectation value of the energy.  In this case, any individual measurement outcome will not necessarily conserve this value, but it is conserved across all outcomes when properly weighted.  So, insofar as you feel many worlds keeps track of all outcomes better than other ways of thinking, we do get a stronger version of conservation of the EV of energy across worlds.  But in real life we only see the EV in the large n limit, where a collapse approach is just as good.

A good way to understand this is to treat the detector quantum mechanically and consider the effect of the "negative result" measurement as discussed in this paper:

https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01889375

Answer (score 0):

The photon's energy comes from the source and nothing is gained after that. Some photons make it through the polarizer and some don't. This does not violate conservation of energy. Photon's that make it through still have their energy. Photons that don't make it through transfer their energy to the polarizer. I don't understand where your concern is? Also, you should not think of polarizers as being strictly filters. They do more than that because every photon that makes it through becomes polarized parallel with the polarizer.This can happen at any angle other than 90 degrees.